# In mysql, I can't create the table, it says that errors code:1005. there are some Chinese annotation

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DATABASE bookstore;
/*用户表*/
CREATE TABLE tb_user(
uid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,/*用户名*/
`password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,/*密码*/
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,/*邮箱*/
`code` CHAR(64) NOT NULL,/*激活码*/
 state BOOLEAN/*用户状态，有两种是否激活*/
 );

/*分类*/
CREATE TABLE category (
cid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/
cname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL/*分类名称*/
);

INSERT  INTO category(cid,cname) VALUES ('1','JavaSE');
INSERT  INTO category(cid,cname) VALUES ('2','JavaEE');
INSERT  INTO category(cid,cname) VALUES ('3','Javascript');

/*图书表*/
CREATE TABLE book (
bid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/
bname VARCHAR(100),/*图书名*/
price DECIMAL(5,1),/*单价*/
author VARCHAR(20),/*作者*/
image VARCHAR(200),/*图片*/
cid CHAR(32),/*所属分类*/
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES category(cid)/*建立主外键关系*/
);

INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('1','Java编程思想（第4版）','75.6','qdmmy6','book_img/9317290-1_l.jpg','1');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('2','Java核心技术卷1','68.5','qdmmy6','book_img/20285763-1_l.jpg','1');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('3','Java就业培训教程','39.9','张孝祥','book_img/8758723-1_l.jpg','1');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('4','Head First java','47.5','（美）塞若','book_img/9265169-1_l.jpg','1');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('5','JavaWeb开发详解','83.3','孙鑫','book_img/22788412-1_l.jpg','2');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('6','Struts2深入详解','63.2','孙鑫','book_img/20385925-1_l.jpg','2');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('7','精通Hibernate','30.0','孙卫琴','book_img/8991366-1_l.jpg','2');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('8','精通Spring2.x','63.2','陈华雄','book_img/20029394-1_l.jpg','2');
INSERT  INTO book VALUES ('9','Javascript权威指南','93.6','（美）弗兰纳根','book_img/22722790-1_l.jpg','3');

SELECT * FROM book;

 /*订单表*/
CREATE TABLE orders (
oid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/
ordertime DATETIME,/*订单生成时间*/
total DECIMAL(10,0),/*订单合计*/
state SMALLINT(1),/*订单状态：未付款、已付款但未发货、已发货但未确认收货、收货已结束*/
 uid CHAR(32),/*订单的主人*/
  address VARCHAR(200),/*订单的收货地址*/
FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES USER (uid)/*建立主外键关系*/
);

SELECT * FROM orders;

/*订单项表*/
CREATE TABLE orderitem (
iid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/
COUNT INT,/*数量*/
subtotal DECIMAL(10,0),/*小计*/
oid CHAR(32),/*所属订单*/
bid CHAR(32),/*订单项所指的商品*/
FOREIGN KEY (oid) REFERENCES orders (oid),/*建立主外键关系*/
FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES book (bid)/*建立主外键关系*/
);
```

the errors messages:

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.003 sec
传送时间   : 2.045 sec

### 总耗时      : 2.048 sec

共 0 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.049 sec
传送时间   : 0.010 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.060 sec

共 0 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.025 sec
传送时间   : 1.022 sec

### 总耗时      : 1.048 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.094 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.095 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.059 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.060 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.044 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.045 sec

共 0 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.007 sec
传送时间   : 0.051 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.059 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.060 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.061 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.092 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.093 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.075 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.076 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.045 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.046 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.010 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.011 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.075 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.075 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.011 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.012 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.074 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.075 sec

共 1 行受到影响

执行耗时   : 0.097 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.097 sec

返回了 9 行

执行耗时   : 0.001 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.001 sec

查询：/*订单表*/ CREATE TABLE orders ( oid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/ ordertime DATETIME,/*订单生成时间*/ total DECIMAL(...

错误代码： 1005
Can't create table 'bookstore.orders' (errno: 150)

执行耗时   : 0 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.025 sec

查询：SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 0, 1000

错误代码： 1146
Table 'bookstore.orders' doesn't exist

执行耗时   : 0 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.001 sec

查询：/*订单项表*/ CREATE TABLE orderitem ( iid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/ COUNT INT,/*数量*/ subtotal DECIMAL(10,0),/*小议.

错误代码： 1005
Can't create table 'bookstore.orderitem' (errno: 150)

执行耗时   : 0 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec

### 总耗时      : 0.056 sec

查询：SELECT * FROM orderitem LIMIT 0, 1000

错误代码： 1146
Table 'bookstore.orderitem' doesn't exist

执行耗时   : 0 sec
传送时间   : 0 sec
总耗时      : 0 sec

How should I solve it?

Comment: If the table doesn't exist, maybe you didn't define it?

Comment: In another vidio,these sentence cereated database and tables successfully. however, in myc ouputer's MYSQL ,the same sentence cann't

Answer (score 0):

When creating table "orders", foreing key reference will be to tb_user, not USER. After creating "orders" table you can create "orderitem" table.

Comment: I change the "User" to "tb_user" ,howeveer, I still fail.查询：CREATE TABLE orders ( oid CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,/*主键*/ ordertime DATETIME,/*订单生成时间*/ total DECIMAL(10,0),/*订单...